# Can CRTP-based derived classes be safely deleted with a virtual destructor in the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions, crtp

I have a c++ question about CRTP pattern and polymorphism. I want to know if I can put a virtual destructor in a CRTP pattern without causing some undefined behavior when implementing a derived class with CRTP.

I have this code for an abstract class:

```
struct TensorExpression {
    virtual ~TensorExpression() = default;
    // ...     
};
```

Then I have derived classes like `BinaryOperator`:

```
template<class Operation>
class BinaryOperator : public TensorExpression {
public:
    ~virtual BinaryOperator() override = default;
    void operation() {
        return static_cast<Operation*>(this)->operation_implementation();
    }
    // some other methods to be implemented with CRTP pattern called with static_cast.
};
```

Then I want to implement those classes with CRTP to avoid more virtual methods.

```
class BinaryAdd : public BinaryOperator<BinaryAdd> {
    public:
    ~BinaryAdd() override = default;
    //
    private:
    friend class public BinaryOperator<BinaryAdd>;
    void operation_implementation() {
        std::cout << "add implementation" ;
    }
    //
};
```

My question is, won't a virtual destructor in a CRTP base class cause undefined behavior? and is it necesary? or is there another whay to delete derived CRTP class using a `TensorExpression` pointer without using a virtual destructor in `BinaryOperator`? I mean, I want to use `TensorExpression` polimorphically, but not `BinaryOperator`; given that I won't be creating `BinaryOperator` pointers directly to be deleted. `BinaryAdd` just implements `BinaryOperator`.

Comment: Note that a template actually doen't exist as a real class, templates get *instantiated*, replacing the template parameters with concrete types or values, once this has been done the specific instantiation is an entirely normal class just as any other one, too...

Comment: If you don't have other virtual methods, you don't need a virtual destructor either. But if you have it anyway it won't cause UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[class.dtor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.dtor#12)

> If a class has a base class with a virtual destructor, its destructor (whether user- or implicitly-declared) is virtual.

You don't need to specify the destructor of `BinaryOperator`. It will be declared `virtual` because `TensorExpression`'s destructor is. Same for `BinaryAdd`.

There is no reason CRTP would prevent dynamic polymorphism from working correctly. Deleting a `BinaryAdd` object through a `TensorExpression` pointer will work just fine, simply because the destructor of `TensorExpression` is virtual.

Your example structure is even listed as a pattern in the [wikipedia page for CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).